# Use jsoup to parse html that has class with a certain beginning

Tags: jsoup

Title is weird, i know. I don't know how to explain it better.

I am using jsoup to parse XML. This is how I did it until now:

```
Elements dan = doc.select("table.ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden tbody tr:eq(0) th:eq("+i+") div");
```

So I am parsing elements that have class name "ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden" ...

But now the website administator changed it so that every day there is a different class name. It still starts with "ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden" but there is something added to it.

Example: "ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden 123"

Is it possible to only look for a certain beginning of class name and then parse it? For example if the calss name begins with "ednevnik-seznam", it will parse it.

Something that can replace everything, like % in SQL.

**EDIT**: This is how I changed the code and it still won't work:

```
Elements dan = doc.select("table[class^=ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden] tbody tr:eq(0) th:eq("+i+") div");
```

**In-depth explanation**:

I'd gladly post HTML code but I don't have access to it. And if I inspect element and then copy/paste it from there, the code is too messed up. So this is the website from which I want to parse HTML: https://www.easistent.com/urniki/cc45c5d0d303f954588402a186f5cdba5edb51d6/razredi/28396

This is the code with which I was doing it *up until now.*

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    Elements dan = doc.select("table[class^=ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden] tbody tr:eq(0) th:eq("+i+") div");
                    for (int b = 1; b <= 11; b++)
                    {
                        Elements predmeti = doc.select("table[class^=ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden] tbody  tr:eq("+b+") td:eq("+predmet+") td[class=text14 bold]");
                        Elements ucilnice = doc.select("table[class^=ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden] tbody  tr:eq("+b+") td:eq("+predmet+")   div[class=text11]");
...
```

So basically what I do with this, I parse every table element specifically.

This was working until something changed on the website. Now table column elements don't have the same class all the time anymore. They used to always be "ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden" but now they change accordnig to which day it is. The column that is currently highlighted has a different class name.

So now this html parser code parses everything except the highlighted column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a CSS selector to select items that start with "ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden".

In your case, your selector would be:

`Elements dan = doc.select("table[class^=ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden]");`

This says to select all tables that have a class name that starts with `ednevnik-seznam_ur_teden`.

And for reference, I find the [jsoup Selector](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) documentation very helpful with examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it sadly doesn't work. It still won't parse those classes that aren't **exactly** "ednevnik-seznamm_ur_teden". Check my edit to see how I changed my code.

Comment: You can remove the `tbody tr:eq(0) th:eq("+i+") div` portion of the select. The first portion should get all your tables that start with the class name.

Comment: But I need that part to parse certain elements of the table. Am I missing something here? Should I give you the full code to understand it better?

Comment: If you could post a sample of the HTML tables that you want to parse, that would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my original question and explained the problem very briefly, I hope it helps.

Comment: Actually, I made this work, you were right. The problem was somewhere else also in my code. Thanks!